# Multiple LEFT JOIN with multiple condition on the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have 3 tables: A, B and C.

Each table has a `Date` and an `x` column.

I want to left join all the tables on the Date with a specific Date ('2022-03-31') in this case.

I tried creating the following view to do so:

```sql
CREATE VIEW v as
SELECT A.Date,
       A.x
       B.x,
       C.x
FROM A
    left join B on A.Date = B.Date and A.Date in ('2022-03-31')
    left join C on A.Date = C.Date and A.Date in ('2022-03-31');
```

But when I use

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Date) FROM v;
```

It shows me all the Date in A instead of only showing me the '2022-03-31' Date.

I also tried to replace the `in ('2022-03-31')` with `='2022-03-31'` but it doesn't works.

Comment: Shouldn't `AND A.Date in ('2022-03-31')` be in the `WHERE`? What you are doing here is only `JOIN`ing the rows when the value of `A.Date` have the date `20220331` but you aren't filtering the data returned from `A` to only be for that date because of the `LEFT JOIN`s.

Comment: i saw in another post that if you want to put a WHERE clause while using a LEFT JOIN you have to put it in the ON instead

Comment: Yes, it's showing all the dates in A because you're selecting everything from A. The left joins only care about B and C. Add a WHERE clause if you want to limit A to a certain date. (a.date = 'your date')

Comment: It does that because of the logic you used in your joins. Logically you are selecting **every row in A** and, along with those rows, the rows in B and C that also join to A for that specific date. I suggest you start over and discuss your goal with the view - it makes little sense as written without more detail from you regarding your goal and your schema.

Comment: @Alan you read the post wrong. If you use a `WHERE` on a column *from* a `LEFT JOIN`ed table then it would turn into an implicit `INNER JOIN`. `A.Date` is from the table `A`, not `B` or `C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a WHERE Clause outside of the left join:

```
CREATE VIEW v as
SELECT A.Date,
       A.x
       B.x,
       C.x
FROM A
    left join B on A.Date = B.Date
    left join C on A.Date = C.Date
WHERE A.Date in ('2022-03-31');
```